# Adding across a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset and I am trying to add across the columns. For example, say there are 50 rows and 100 columns. For each row I want to go through specific columns (not all) and add the results.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

`apply(df[,c(1,5,10,11,15)],1,sum)` will add columns 1,5,10,11, and 15.

Comment: Thank you that helps so much! What if I want to show in a new output that in one column I add columns 1,5,10,11 and 15.... then the next column I add 3,6,and 7.  Is that possible?

Comment: Just do this (or use the rowSums function, which as DWin notes is generally faster) twice, and stick the results together with `cbind`

Comment: e.g. `cbind(rowSums(df[,c(1,5,10,11,15)]),rowSums(df[,c(3,6,7)]))`

Answer (score 2):

`rowSums` is generally faster than `apply(dat, 1, sum)`. Furthermore they both may need to have an additional argument to prevent NA values for sabotaging the results.

```
rowSums( dat[ , cols_to_sum] , na.rm=TRUE )
```

If you want to have an irregular selection of columns, i.e. different columns from different rows,  then that too is possible but you will need to clarify the question.